# How do I show the value of the cell in column c on another seet based on the values in column a and b?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, formula

I have 2 sheets. The first sheet has 2 dropdowns with values matching columns in the 2nd sheet in column a and b. based on the user's selections in the sheet one drop downs, I would like to show the content of the cell c of the corresponding row.

For example: 
User selects apples in dropdown c3 on sheet 1 and lemons in drop down c5 on sheet 1, both of which match values on sheet 2 in cells a7 and b7, now show the value in cell c7 from sheet 2 on sheet 1 cell c7.

Comment: `If()` statements? [What have you tried so far](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell C7 type this formula:

`=Index(Sheet2!C:C,Match(C3&C5,Sheet2!A:A&Sheet2!B:B,0))`

Then press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` so it becomes an array formula.

If you like, you can restrict the rows instead of using the entire column.

Comment: Thanks Scott! This has had me twisted all morning. You saved my butt.